# How to make the check all button only work when click on remove all btn

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code as below.

When i click on the checkbox button All at the top, then click on individual row Remove button also will close it which i don't want. I only want it work on Remove All (button blue at the bottom)

```
[Demo] http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/14900/
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Update the click function of individual remove button as shown below

```
//Click on individual row
  $('.remove-row').click(function(event){
    $(this).closest('tr.pointer').remove();
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Comment: ops.. just saw you have amended code thanks so much for you time :D